# save an integer change to a model in the database error

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add the possibility to add a quantity to the products I add to my cart. I added an integerfield to the product model as, which acts as a placeholder (want to reset it after checkout). I don't know if this is the best way to do this, but I think it might work haha :-)
When I want to save the quantity, which prints fine in the terminal, it gives the following error.. How can I avoid this?

```
AttributeError at /scan/stock/

'int' object has no attribute 'save'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/scan/stock/
Django Version:     1.11
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'int' object has no attribute 'save'
```

I cant figure out why quantity won't save to the database this way...

```
    def scan_to_cart(request):
        form = forms.ScanSessionForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            product = None
            barcode = request.POST.get('barcode_input')
            amount  = request.POST.get('amount_input')
            queryset = Child.objects.filter(product_id_code=barcode)
            if queryset.exists():
                try:
                    # the queryset is already filtered by the barcode
                    # now we apply an extra filter to check if this user has the product
                    product = queryset.get(user=request.user)
                except Child.DoesNotExist:
                    # here we are sure this product exists, but this user doesnt have it in the stock.
                    messages.error(request, 'I can\'t find any inventory with this barcode')
            else:
                # here we know this product doesnt exist
                messages.error(request, 'I can\'t find any inventory with this barcode')
            if product is not None:
                form = forms.ScanSessionForm(request.POST, instance=product)
                if form.is_valid():

                    product_obj = product.id
                    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
                    products = cart_obj.products.all()
                    cart_obj.products.add(product_obj)

# It's about this section of code
                    quantity = product.session_amount
                    print (quantity)
                    quantity += int(amount)
                    print (quantity)
                quantity.save()

                messages.success(request, '%s - %s was successfully added to cart' % (product.product_name, product.sku))   
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/scan/stock/')
    else:
        form = forms.ScanSessionForm()
    return render(request, 'stockscan/scan_to_cart.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: may be you want `product.save()` instead of `quantity.save()` or other model instance?

Comment: just for fun, what is difference between the answer and my comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to save `quantity` that is an `int`. What you probably want to do is attributing the new quantity to the product first and then saving the product:

```
quantity = product.session_amount
quantity += int(amount)
product.session_amount = quantity
product.save()
```

Or even quicker:

```
product.session_amount += int(amount)
product.save()
```